# Non-equal space between divs

Tags: html, css

I have several divs with margin-bottom: 5px. What it's not logic to me is, that spacing between divs is not equal. If I insert some text into div, space decreases. Without text, space increases.

Here is [example from code pen](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/BzvXoB?editors=1100)

It looks like this:

[image]

All divs have position: relative and margin-bottom: 5px:

```
.divNote{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 60px;  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #FAC28A;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #003399;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;    
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `float:left` to `.divNote` this will work.

```css
@border: 1px;

.divMain{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;  
}

.divNote{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 60px;  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #FAC28A;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #003399;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;    
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}

.divNoteDatum{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;   
  font-weight: bold;      
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5px;
  color: #003399;
}

.divUpper{
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain" class="divMain">

  <div class="divUpper"></div>

  <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- divMain -->
```

Comment: It works... but how come? I would never think about this. How is float connected to the margin-bottom?

Comment: I forget why though, there are a lot of articles on this but I can't get google to work with me (I've read some articles)

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top` for the inline-block divNote elements. Some overflow of content of inline-block elements causes this issue. Its always good practice to use vertical-align

```css
@border: 1px;

.divMain{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;  
}

.divNote{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  float: left;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 60px;  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #FAC28A;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #003399;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;    
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.divNoteDatum{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;   
  font-weight: bold;      
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5px;
  color: #003399;
}

.divUpper{
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain" class="divMain">

  <div class="divUpper"></div>

  <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    test<br/>test<br/>test
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>
  
    <div id="divNote" class="divNote">
    
    <div id="divNoteDatum" class="divNoteDatum">12.08.2016 11:08</div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- divMain -->
```